# Dash-to-Dock icon size

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

I have been using Dash-to-Dock on Ubuntu 18.04 since April and updating my installation regularly. Recently the icons in the Dash-to-Dock (the ones in the screen that open when you click "Show Applications", not the ones in the dock) change size without any warning. Sometimes they are big, sometimes medium and sometimes so tiny I cannot identify the app from them.

Below is a screenshot.

I know how to change the size of the icons in the dash but cannot find a way to alter the size of the icons in the application screen.

[image]

Comment: Have you installed Dash-to-Dock manually? Or just using the pre-installed Ubuntu dock extension (which is a fork of Dash-to-Dock)?

Comment: To be honest I can't remember exactly. I switched from Unity to Gnome under 17.04 in as preparation for 18.04 and must have installed dash-to-dock then, so I guess it would have been manually. I then updated to 17.10 and 18.04 when they were offered in the updater.

Comment: This is certainly abnormal behaviour. It could be related to your upgrade path. I am pretty sure the issue will not be there if you do a fresh reinstall.